# how to bluid unity project correctly into android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, virtual-reality

i'm trying to develop an Augumented reality app , and i begin by simple exemple an image target and a gameobject (cube) appear on it , the result show succefully in unity , but when i try to build the project to android device , the screen of device change completly and no (cube ) appear .

this is how it appear in mobile device http://i59.tinypic.com/2ljjqcg.png

but in unity it work good, http://i59.tinypic.com/2nv4cq9.png

Comment: its very difficult to say without your code and screens. I will recommend to download Unity Remote app for android and then test before building

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `ARcamera>Camera>BackgroundPlane` video material from `custom/videoBackground` to `custom/renderedVideoBackground`.

Also, ensure you've used the correct Vuforia `License Keys` for the Database being used.